# Separating names separated by "| character" to individual pairs

Tags: sed, awk

I want to separate the names in the same line into separate individual pairs.

```
TMPRSS2|pp9284 AADAT Sample1
ERG    TMPRSS2|pp9284 Sample2
TMPRSS2|pp9284 ETV1 Sample3
PDE4A   MIA|MIA-RAB4B|RAB4B|RAB4B-EGLN2|EGLN2 Sample4
```

This should be

```
TMPRSS2 AADAT Sample1
pp9284 AADAT Sample1
ERG    TMPRSS2 Sample2
ERG  pp9284 Sample2
TMPRSS2 ETV1 Sample3
pp9284 ETV1 Sample3
PDE4A MIA Sample4
PDE4A MIA-RAB4B Sample4
PDE4A RAB4B Sample4
PDE4A RAB4B-EGLN2 Sample4
PDE4A EGLN2 Sample4
```

The multiple names are in both the columns so I want individual pairs.I have tried mysql for this as after I have individual pairs I want to compare it with a another table.
strsplit in R only works well when the multiple names are in a fixed number.but they vary in each line.
Can I do this using sed,awk?

Also there are certain columns,whose values remain same and basically they remain same for the values that were in the same line .How should I print those out .I  added the 3rd column,whose values get replicated into new lines.for this I used print $3 inside the for loop to print them out as well,but dos not work.

Comment: Please add an example to illustrate the second requirement (i.e. the lines that should remain the same).

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{split($1,a,"|"); split($2,b,"|"); for (i in a) {for (j in b) print a[i],b[j];}}' file
TMPRSS2 AADAT
pp9284 AADAT
ERG TMPRSS2
ERG pp9284
TMPRSS2 ETV1
pp9284 ETV1
PDE4A RAB4B-EGLN2
PDE4A EGLN2
PDE4A MIA
PDE4A MIA-RAB4B
PDE4A RAB4B
```

To also print the third (`SampleN`) field, you can just add `$3` to the print statement inside the loops, i.e.

```
$ awk '{split($1,a,"|"); split($2,b,"|"); for (i in a) {for (j in b) print a[i],b[j],$3;}}' file
TMPRSS2 AADAT Sample1
pp9284 AADAT Sample1
ERG TMPRSS2 Sample2
ERG pp9284 Sample2
TMPRSS2 ETV1 Sample3
pp9284 ETV1 Sample3
PDE4A RAB4B-EGLN2 Sample4
PDE4A EGLN2 Sample4
PDE4A MIA Sample4
PDE4A MIA-RAB4B Sample4
PDE4A RAB4B Sample4
```

Comment: Also there are certain columns,whose values remain same and basically they duplicate .How should I print those out .I added $3,$4 inside the for loop.

Comment: @ron, don't add requirements as comments to someone's answer -- put them in your question

Comment: the code for gene names work perfect,its just i forgot to mention this.

Comment: i was trying the same thing but the problem was the txt file was in a classic mac format.I changed to unix format to be readable by awk

Answer (score 4):

With bash:

```
# important to use parentheses, not braces, to localize changes to IFS
# the variable is purposefully unquoted
split_pipe() ( IFS='|'; echo $1 )

while read -r first second third; do
  for word1 in $(split_pipe "$first"); do
    for word2 in $(split_pipe "$second"); do
      echo $word1 $word2 $third
    done
  done
done < file
```

Comment: You need to `set -f` here or you might glob. The example data doesn't include any glob characters, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` you can do:

```
sed -E 's/(\|[^ |]+) /\1| /
        s/(([^|]* )?([^|]*))\|(([^ ]*)(.*))/\1\6\n\2\4/
        /\n/P;D' <infile
```

...which prints...

```
TMPRSS2 AADAT Sample1
pp9284 AADAT Sample1
ERG    TMPRSS2 Sample2
ERG    pp9284 Sample2
TMPRSS2 ETV1 Sample3
pp9284 ETV1 Sample3
PDE4A   MIA Sample4
PDE4A   MIA-RAB4B Sample4
PDE4A   RAB4B Sample4
PDE4A   RAB4B-EGLN2 Sample4
PDE4A   EGLN2 Sample4
```

It works by dividing up and printing then deleting in piecemeal the contents of a line on extra `\n`ewline characters. The `P` command `P`rints only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space, so you can fairly easily print only a portion of your edit buffer as you like.

In this case for every pipe-divided section which does not contain spaces `sed` puts all of the bits at either end of the edit buffer in twice. `sed` inserts the leftmost and rightmost ends to the left and right of the left-most pipe-divided section and follows that sequence with a `\n`ewline, it then puts the same selections to either end of all of the pipe-divided sections that remain on the right-hand side of its inserted `\n`ewline. So `sed` can `P`rint only the bit on the left if there is a `\n`ewline in pattern-space at all, then `D`elete only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern-space and try again.

The very first substitution only ever happens once - it just appends a pipe to the end of the pipe-divided sections so there will always be a pipe to separate on - even for the last occurrence. The rest of the time, `sed` does the one `s///`ubstitution, `P`rints the first line in pattern-space, then `D`eletes same. When it cannot do that any longer it `D`eletes *all* of pattern-space and pulls in the next input line automatically.

A POSIX BRE for doing the same thing could be written:

```
sed '   s/\(|[^ |]\{1,\}\) /\1| /
        s/^\(\( *[^ |]*  *\)*\([^ |]*\)\)|\(\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)\)/\1\6\
\2\4/;   /\n/P;D' <infile
```